# Ruby meta-programming - How can I set an instance's attr_accessor value through class method?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to write a ruby module with some meta-programming features, but I'm getting a bit confused.

```
module MetaModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def my_method(attribute)
      # Define an attr_accessor for the original class
      attr_accessor :test_accessor

      # This is clearly wrong, but I don't know what is correct
      self.test_accessor ||= []
      self.test_accessor << attribute
    end
  end
end

class MyClass
  include MetaModule

  my_method :name
  my_method :age
  my_method :city
end
```

My desired output is: `MyClass.new.test_accessor => [:name, :age, :city]`

Comment: when you will tag as Ruby,please give Ruby related stuffs...Not ROR..

Comment: This isn't Rails related.  Just because I like to use ActiveSupport packages, this code somehow becomes non-ruby?

Comment: Do you get an error? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The place in my code where I call `self.test_accessor`, I get an error stating that such a method does not exist (which I know, I just have no idea how to interact with the instance variable I just defined).

My desired output is listed at the bottom of my post.

Comment: why you put `attr_accessor :test_accessor` inside the method? :) I am trying to understand,what you are trying to do...

Comment: by putting `attr_accessor :test_accessor` in the class method, I've defined that accessor for whichever class I include the module in.  So now `MyClass` will have an accessor named `test_accessor`

Comment: `my_method` is not a class method..it is an instance method.. dear!! :)

Comment: Actually, it does function as a class method when you wrap it in the ClassMethods module. Calling it as a class method (without the lines I've shows as errors) works fine.  The responses below show my statement to be correct.

Comment: Bryce, if you think about it a bit: you're adding class-level code and you want it to set value for an instance. But *which instance*? There can be many. Maybe you just want a class-level method?

Comment: I understand that it's a confusing idea.  I would like it to be set for _each_ instance.  Think of it as setting a default value for each instance upon initialization, but one that can be defined through a class method.

Comment: @Bryce: maybe a constant, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be a little bit of a mix up here. It is certainly possible to construct a module that will have your desired output, but ultimately it will look something like this

```
module MetaModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def my_method(attribute)
      # Define an attr_accessor for the original class
      @class_test_accessor ||= []
      @class_test_accessor << attribute
    end

    def class_test_accessor
      @class_test_accessor
    end
  end

  def test_accessor
    self.class.class_test_accessor
  end
end
```

But you might notice that ultimately we are adding an instance method that simply accesses a class instance variable. Because `my_method` is a class method, its value wont change per instance. Therefore I would suggest accessing it simply as `self.class.class_test_accessor` within an instance. If there is something else you were hoping to accomplish w/ `my_method` (like seed a `class_test_accessor` and then modify per instance) let me know and I will try to help.